# fetching the status code from json array

Tags: java, android

i have to find the status of the the json response.How can i fetch the status from json array or how can check if the status code of the response is 200

```
{
    "assetDetails": [
        {
            " assetNo": "rocket",
            "assetName": "VIN Bullet"
        },
        {
            "assetNo": "Asset2",
            "assetName": "VIN Bullet"
        },
        {
            "assetNo": "rocket",
            "assetName": "VIN Bullet"
        }
    ],
    "status": "200"
}
```

Comment: You can not use `getstatuscode()` method for get  status key from your JSON response, `getstatuscode()` is used to get status code from HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

If you got your response in JSON format. You can try below method.

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(<Your JSON Response>);
        String strStatus = jsonObject.getString("status");

        // Now your status stored in strStatus variable, you can now do any thing with that variable.

    } catch (JSONException je) {
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    try {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
        String status=obj.getString("status");
        if(status.equals("200"))
        {

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: cant we use getstatuscode()?